# Rename a sub-document field within an Array of an Document

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, robo3t

***I am trying to rename the particular child field inside an array of an collection in MONGODB***

```
{
"_id" : Id("248NSAJKH258"),
"isGoogled" : true,
"toCrawled" : true,
"result" : [ 
    {
        "resultsId" : 1,
        "title" : "Text Data to be writen",
        "googleRanking" : 1,
        "isrelated" : false
    }, 
    {
        "resultId" : 2,
        "title" : "Text Data",
        "googleRanking" : 2,
        "isrelated" : true
    }]
```

**I need to rename "isrelated" to "related" ** from the collection document
Using mongo Version 4.0

I Tried :

```
db.collection_name.update({}, { $rename: { 'result.isrelated': 'result.related'} } )
```

But it didn't worked in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in official documentation $rename not working for arrays.
Please check link below:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/

But you can do something like this

```
let newResult = [];

db.aa1.find({}).forEach(doc => {
    for (let i in doc.result) {
        newResult.push({
            "resultsId" : doc.result[i]['resultsId'],
            "title" : doc.result[i]['title'],
            "googleRanking" : doc.result[i]['googleRanking'],
            "related" : doc.result[i]['isrelated'],
        })
    }

    db.aa1.updateOne({_id: doc._id}, {$set: {result: newResult}});
    newResult = []
})
```